# Debugging and detect cause nil objects and fatal error index out of range

Tags: ios, debugging, swift3, fatal-error

I have large project with my role being fixing bugs, and many bugs were fatal index out of range error. I know it is an array index not found error, but real problem is which statement causing the problem or which variable.

I tried instruments with no luck, debugging the problem is too hard as scenario is being a bit random.

Can you help me with a way to debug such bugs?

Comment: If you're running with Xcode, set automatic breakpoints on Swift errors and Objective-C exceptions using the Breakpoint Navigator.  If you're running outside Xcode, symbolicate the crash logs and look at the crashed stack for where it failed.

Comment: can you please explain how to do it more in details? @PhilipMills